# How to set ResponseWriter to non-default in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I have the following code, which is simply searching the Solr Server.

```
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery searchquery = new SolrQuery("company profile");
QueryResponse response = server.query(searchquery)
```

I want to have the response in json, other than the default which is xml. So I went into the solrconfig.xml file and enabled the following line:

```
<queryResponseWriter name="json" class="org.apache.solr.request.JSONResponseWriter" />
```

However, from the console, I'm still getting wt=javabin encoded to the search query request.

Also, I've modified the above code like this:

```
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery searchquery = new SolrQuery("company profile");
searchquery.setParam("wt", "json");
QueryResponse response = server.query(searchquery)
```

But I'm still getting `wt=javabin` encoded and `wt=json` also appended, such that the query now looks like this:

```
webapp/solr path=/select params={wt=javabin&wt=json}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SolrJ only supports the `javabin` and `xml` formats (configurable with [CommonHttpSolrServer.setParser](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html#setParser%28org.apache.solr.client.solrj.ResponseParser%29)).

But why would you want to use JSON? Javabin is by far the format which provides the best decompression speed, its drawback being that is is not human-readable, on the contrary to JSON and XML (which is not a problem in this case since SolrJ is parsing the result for you).

Comment: OMG! I never knew. That's a big draw back. I need json because my client-side integration is Javascript.

Comment: This doesn't mean that you cannot query Solr from Javascript, just make a common HTTP call using wt=json and parse it in javascript. SolrJ is only a library which makes it easy to call Solr from any JVM language.

Comment: I found json-lib which is interesting. I will simply use this to morph the xml to json, then have javascript to take it from there.

Comment: You don't need to morph the xml to json, just make an HTTP request with the wt=json parameter (http://solr-instace:solr-port/solr/core/select?wt=json&q=query) and parse the result in javascript.

Comment: Well, I don't need Javascript to make the request (web tier). I just need it for presentation and templating. That's how the architecture of the project is designed. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With SolrJ and json-lib, I was able to get json response like this:

```
SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery searchquery = new SolrQuery("company profile");
QueryResponse response = server.query(searchquery)

JSONArray jsonObject = JSONArray.fromObject( response.getResults() );
log.log(Level.INFO, "received jsonObject is {0}", jsonObject.toString());
Iterator data = jsonObject.iterator();

SolrResultBean bean = new SolrResultBean();
List output = new ArrayList();
while(data.hasNext()) {
  output.add(data.next());
}
log.log(Level.INFO, "json items in the List are {0}", output);
bean.setObject(output);

// wicket page redirect
setResponsePage(SearchPage.class, new PageParameters());
```