# SOLR convert JSON response to javabin

Tags: java, serialization, solr, lucene, solrj

Is it possible to convert the JSON response returned by SOLR to javabin and return it to client.

Basically my service acts as proxy between client and SOLR. The client expects the response in javabin and I have to convert the response returned by SOLR to javabin and return to client. How can I achieve this?

I basically want to convert the already deserialized javabin response to javabin and send to client.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this link may be useful to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605629/how-to-set-responsewriter-to-non-default-in-solr.

Comment: I want to convert the SOLR response in JSON or any format back to javabin

Comment: so u want to convert solr response into javabin, am i right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214439/parsing-solr-results-javabin-format

Comment: I want to convert the javabin response which SolrJ deserializes back to Javabin.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out, but you need to set the javabin format while querying. Add `wt=javabin` to the URL.

Through SolrJ API

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server =...
server.setParser(new BinaryResponseParser());
```

More info [javabin](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/javabin)

If you want to serialize the SolrResponse you can use [BinaryResponseWriter.write()](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/response/BinaryResponseWriter.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream,%20org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest,%20org.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse%29)

Comment: I know that wt=javabin will return the javabin response. But I want to convert the javabin response which SolrJ deserializes back to Java object modify some fields in the Java object and send it back to the client. How can I achieve this?

Comment: isn't clear when you say you want to convert deserialized response to java object. it is already deserialized to java object by SolrJ. Please also share your SolrJ code

Comment: I want to convert back the deserialized object to javabin and return to the client. I don't want to deserialize a already deserialized java object.

Comment: when you say you want to convert to javabin, do mean that you want to serialize it again?

Comment: Yeah I want to serialize it again.

Comment: then you can use SolrJ API to serialize it back. Updated the answer

Comment: Which SolrJ API I can use to serialize it?

Comment: BinaryResponseWriter is not part of SolrJ library. So I can't use it.

Comment: if the answer and discussion were helpful, please accept the answer